# Laravel joining two tables column id in where clause ambiguous

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm trying to join a table in my Laravel project based on a common column value. I have two tables:

1. Reports
2. Report data

A single report contains a field called `report_data_id` gets updated at some point and contains the report data ID from that table, however, regardless of whether I use the `id` column or an entirely seperate column, or different type of join, I get the following error regardless:

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'id' in where clause is ambiguous

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here in my code?

```php
$report = DB::table('reports')
            ->where('id', $id)
            ->where('user_id', Auth::id())
            ->join('report_data', 'report_data.id', '=', 'reports.report_data_id')
            ->first();
```

I need to first select the report where the ID matches the requested ID from my request, and where the User ID matches the logged in user, this is important so not to get the incorrect report.

I then need to get the report data from the `report_data` table where that table contains an `id`, the default `id` column matches the `report_data_id` column from my reports table.

I've tried adding a separate column to my `report_data` table, but this doesn't work.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the following code. Use the alias because your query doesn't specify which alias to use for `id` column.

```
$report = DB::table('reports')
            ->where('reports.id', $id)
            ->where('reports.user_id', Auth::id())
            ->join('report_data', 'report_data.id', '=', 'reports.report_data_id')
            ->first();
```

Answer (score 1):

In this query there will both be `report_data` and `reports`, since they both have an `id` column, `MySql` don't know which to use. Specify the id column and it will work.

```
->where('reports.id', $id)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write `where('reports.id', $id)` to remove ambiguity.

Full Query

```
$report = DB::table('reports')
            ->where('reports.id', $id)
            ->where('user_id', Auth::id())
            ->join('report_data', 'report_data.id', '=', 'reports.report_data_id')
            ->first();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$report = DB::table('reports')
            ->where('reports.id', $id)
            ->where('reports.user_id', Auth::id())
            ->join('report_data', 'report_data.id', '=', 'reports.report_data_id')
            ->first();
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.